# Cannot unload built-in keyboard on macbook pro(kext unload)

Tags: macos, keyboard, kernel-extension

Because my keyboard was repeating countlessly several keys without even touching them, i tried to solve the issue by unloading the built-in keyboard and connecting an external keyboard till i find a solution. Therefore, i used kext to unload my keyboard with the following command:

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext
```

However, the terminal returns my this error:

```
(kernel) Can't remove kext com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard; services failed to terminate - 0xe00002c7.
Failed to unload com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard - (iokit/common) unsupported function.
```

I googled the error but didn't find much about it. Can someone please help me? :')

Comment: I am having the same issue. The above command used to work for me on Sierra, but doesn't work on catalina since I upgraded.

Comment: Yes, I am in the same situation. It worked fine in Mojave. I just did a security update or whatever and it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're running into some new protections in SIP. See csrutil(8) but I think the fix is:

- Boot to recovery mode by shutting down and then hold ⌘ R.
- In recovery mode open Terminal by selecting it from utilities in the menu bar
- Run csrutil disable
- Reboot and kextunload should work.

Disclaimer: I don't know what you're losing in terms of security by disabling this.

Comment: I am afraid that this solution doesn't work. I have already disabled SIP